# Error de sintaxis en metodo java

Tags: java

Tengo este codigo donde debo devolver un booleano:

```
public boolean isFull(){
    int contf=0;
    for(int i = 0; i<parqueo.length;i++){
        if(parqueo[contf]!=vacio){
            if(contf==parqueo.length-1){
                return true;
            }else{
                contf++;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

pero el error dice que no he devuelto un valor.

Error:

> ParkingLot.java:32: error: missing return statement
>           }
>           ^
>   ParkingLot.java:48: error: missing return statement
>           }
>           ^
>   2 errors

Como podría solucionarlo.

Comment: siempre debes retornar algo, prueba agregar un return false al final del código. Después del for

Comment: Gracias Franco! fijate que si funciona pero debe poder decidir si enviar verdadero si se cumple la condicion o falso si no... Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguramente por que no rompes/detienes el ciclo, intenta colocar un **break** en el segundo if cuando encuentres el valor que quieres así:

```
public boolean isFull(){
int contf=0; boolean vf;
for(int i = 0; i<parqueo.length;i++){
    if(parqueo[contf]!=vacio){
        if(contf==parqueo.length-1){
            vf = true; break; // AQUI
        }else{
            contf++;
        }
    } else {
        vf = false; break;
    }
}
return vf;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda! fijate que me aparece unreachable Statement

Comment: revisa mi edición

Comment: Gracias Leonard!! Funciono!

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado, ahora marca la respuesta para que otros no contesten innecesariamente y otros la encuentren mas rápido si la llegan a necesitar.

Comment: buenas, no creo que el problema sea el break (por más que sea más performante) sino que si el if "contf==.." nunca se cumple el método no iba a retornar nada, de ahí el error. El método siempre debe retornar (true or false) y al haber un if else, se debe contemplar las dos situaciones. Bien resuelves vos creando una variable, pero es lo mismo que poner return false al final.. pues por defecto se inicializa en falso. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias Leonard y Franco! gracias por compartir su conocimiento.